# NLTK and MaltParser exit with error code 1

Tags: java, python, ubuntu, nltk

I've looked all over for an answer to this question, but haven't found an answer that suits my needs.

I'm trying to use the nltk wrapper for the MaltParser. It seems that there have been lots of people who have had problems with the nltk wrapper for MaltParser in t the past, but none I've found with the same error or the same fixes. Here is the code and here is the error:

```
import nltk
maltParser = nltk.parse.malt.MaltParser(parser_dirname="/home/owen/maltparser-1.7.2", 
model_filename="engmalt.linear-1.7",
additional_java_args=['-Xmx512m'])
result = maltParser.parse_one('This is a test sentence'.split())
print result.tree()
```

Here is the error:

> Exception: MaltParser parsing (java -Xmx512m -cp /home/owen/maltparser-1.7.2/lib/libsvm.jar:/home/owen/maltparser-1.7.2/malt.jar:/home/owen/maltparser-1.7.2/lib/log4j.jar:/home/owen/maltparser-1.7.2/maltparser-1.7.2.jar:/home/owen/maltparser-1.7.2/lib/liblinear-1.8.jar org.maltparser.Malt -c engmalt.linear-1.7 -i /tmp/malt_input.conll.ej6hqf -o /tmp/malt_output.conll.TZXpc2 -m parse) failed with exit code 1

Here are the things I've already tried all together and in different combinations:

1. updating nltk and java.
2. trying different versions of the MaltParser and the .mco model file
3. renaming the .jar file in the MaltParser to be Malt.jar (apparently this was a fix that had to be done at some point for the nltk wrapper for certain versions)
4. Editing the os variables for MALT_PARSER='/home/owen/maltparser-1.7.2/' and MALT_MODEL='/home/owen/maltparser-1.7.2/engmalt.poly-1.7.mco'
5. Moving the .mco file in and out of the maltparser-1.7.2 directory

FYI: I have already followed the steps on the following post:

[Step by step to getting malt parser in NLTK to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207394/step-by-step-to-getting-malt-parser-in-nltk-to-work?lq=1)

There might be some other I've tried. I can't remember. What I really want to know is what the error means and what might be causing it. I can't make head or tail of it.

Here is the information that has been requested:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
owen@termedev:~/malttesting$ python -c "import nltk; print nltk.__version__"
3.2.1
owen@termedev:~/malttesting$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

owen@termedev:~/malttesting$ python -c "import os; print os.environ['MALT_PARSER']; print os.environ['MALT_MODEL']"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'MALT_PARSER'
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: I've just tried the `TL;DR` on a fresh ubuntu 16.04 and it seems to works fine, even with `mp = MaltParser('maltparser-1.8.1', 'engmalt.linear-1.7.mco', additional_java_args=['-Xmx512m'])`.

Comment: So we'll need some more information so that we can help you better. Are you on ubuntu? If so, please update your question with output from the terminal of `$ lsb_release -a` and `$ python -c "import nltk; print nltk.__version__` and `$ java -version` and `python -c "import os; print os.environ['MALT_PARSER']; print os.environ['MALT_MODEL']"`

Comment: BTW, I think you didn't really install/update java, thus the exit code 1 error, try these instructions: http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/#

Comment: I ran the commands here at the URL you posted ( tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/#) and it output the same error

Comment: Java 1.8+ don't play well with malt 1.7, can you use malt 1.8.1 instead?

Comment: Can you also list where you have saved your `engmalt.linear-1.7.mco` file?

Comment: Yes, I've tried using it before, but maybe with the updates that it did to Java there on that post you made, i'll try it again. I'll let you know in a bit.

Comment: Can you run all the `TL;DR` instructions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207394/step-by-step-to-getting-malt-parser-in-nltk-to-work?lq=1 and show the output and the errors you have gotten?

Comment: the .mco file is in the malt directory. I've tried it both ways, within and without.

Comment: Please run the following command on the command line, copy and paste the whole command and then update the question with the error if you see one: `cd && wget http://www.maltparser.org/mco/english_parser/engmalt.linear-1.7.mco && wget http://maltparser.org/dist/maltparser-1.8.1.zip && unzip maltparser-1.8.1.zip && export MALT_PARSER=$HOME/maltparser-1.8.1/ && export MALT_MODEL=$HOME/engmalt.linear-1.7.mco`

Comment: After the command on the terminal, run this command on the terminal too: `python -c "from nltk.parse.malt import MaltParser; mp = MaltParser('maltparser-1.8.1', 'engmalt.linear-1.7.mco'); mp.parse_one('I shot an elephant in my pajamas .'.split()).tree()"`

Comment: Hello! I ran the TL;DR instructions from stackoverflow.com/questions/13207394/... and it worked! :) So, now it is working when running python like that from a terminal, but not when the same python code is executed in a .py file.

Comment: So there's some python setup issues. between your terminal and the python code. That'll be hard to debug through stackoverflow and it's dependent on how you setup your python code. Is it through an IDE?

Comment: Try create a fresh virtual environment (http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/), reinstall NLTK and whichever python modules you would use through `pip` under an virtual env and then try running your code again.

Comment: No. Sometimes I use ipython, but it doesn't work with python or ipython. i'm just running the code like this: owen@termedev:~/malttesting$ python malttest.py. Could it have to do with the fact that the .py code is being run in a separate directory? (malttesting) Could it have to do with the environmental variables not working when run in that way?

Comment: You would have to check that the environment variable is setup properly, use `os.environ` to check. Otherwise the full path should also work. Try the virtual environment solution, it will also help you in future work.

Comment: I just moved the file malttest.py into the home directory where I was running the python in from the terminal and it worked. Why is that, that it functions if the malttest.py is located in the home directory and run there, it works, but if it is n a different directory, it doesn't.

Comment: Ah ha, the `os.environ` isn't setup properly in the directory that you use to run your python script.

Comment: Okay. What is the best way to fix that?

Comment: Check out the answer ;P

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that might have gone wrong:

## Problem 1: Java or NLTK versions not updated

First check that you have **installed and updated your NLTK**:

```
$ pip install -U nltk
```

And to **update your Java on Ubuntu**, see http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/#

---

## Problem 2: MaltParser not updated

Try to work with MaltParser version > 1.8 with the appropriate `.mco` files (e.g. `engmalt.linear-1.7`)

---

## Problem 3: Setting Up NLTK API to MaltParser

Then go through the steps in `TL;DR` instructions from [Step by step to getting malt parser in NLTK to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207394/step-by-step-to-getting-malt-parser-in-nltk-to-work?lq=1)

In short, you should see NO error when you run this on the terminal:

```
cd && wget http://www.maltparser.org/mco/english_parser/engmalt.linear-1.7.mco && wget http://maltparser.org/dist/maltparser-1.8.1.zip && unzip maltparser-1.8.1.zip && export MALT_PARSER=$HOME/maltparser-1.8.1/ && export MALT_MODEL=$HOME/engmalt.linear-1.7.mco
python -c "from nltk.parse.malt import MaltParser; mp = MaltParser('maltparser-1.8.1', 'engmalt.linear-1.7.mco'); mp.parse_one('I shot an elephant in my pajamas .'.split()).tree()"
```

---

## Problem 4: Environmental Variables not setup properly

You have to change to the directory where you are running your script and then set the environment variable on the terminal before running your script:

```
cd /home/username/directory_where_you_are_going_to_run_your_script
export MALT_PARSER=$HOME/maltparser-1.8.1/
export MALT_MODEL=$HOME/engmalt.linear-1.7.mco
python yourscript.py
```

---

## Unsolicited answer

If the solutions to the problems listed above didn't resolve your problem with MaltParser API in NLTK, then it's best that you

1. Ensure that you have installed Java correctly, see http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/#
2. Setup a virtual environment (see http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)
3. Install NLTK and the packages that your script needs using `pip`
4. Run the following on the terminal

[on terminal]:

```
cd && wget http://www.maltparser.org/mco/english_parser/engmalt.linear-1.7.mco && wget http://maltparser.org/dist/maltparser-1.8.1.zip && unzip maltparser-1.8.1.zip && export MALT_PARSER=$HOME/maltparser-1.8.1/ && export MALT_MODEL=$HOME/engmalt.linear-1.7.mco
python -c "from nltk.parse.malt import MaltParser; mp = MaltParser('maltparser-1.8.1', 'engmalt.linear-1.7.mco'); mp.parse_one('I shot an elephant in my pajamas .'.split()).tree()"
```

Then afterwards re-run your script after setting up the environmental variables, e.g. with:

```
cd /home/username/directory_where_you_are_going_to_run_your_script
export MALT_PARSER=$HOME/maltparser-1.8.1/
export MALT_MODEL=$HOME/engmalt.linear-1.7.mco
python yourscript.py
```